# Найти количество одинаковых символов в числе

Tags: python, python-3.x

Например дано число 187555777909433545. Надо найти количество четверок и семерок в числе.

Comment: надо - делайте, в чем проблема то  ?

Answer (score 2):

превращаем в строку и с помощью метода `count` считаем количество `4` и `7`

```
num = 187555777909433545 
num = str(num) 
print(num.count("4"), num.count("7"))
```

Можно решить без использования строк:

```
def f(num):
    a, b = 0, 0
    while num:
        if num % 10 == 4:
            a += 1
        elif num % 10 == 7:
            b += 1
        
        num //= 10
    return a, b

print(f(187555777909433545))
```

Comment: +1 за решение без использования строк)